# How to model solar photovoltaic array in spice?

Tags: power-electronics, solar-cell, solar-energy, kicad, ngspice

This is the circuit I need to simulate in KiCad and ngspice.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHlOgU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can I encapsulate the above circuit into a variable in ngspice so that when designing a pv array or module I just need to enter the number of cells for a module? Is it possible in ngspice?

KiCad model:

[image]

ngspice simulation:

[image]

Netlist for ngspice:

```
.title KiCad schematic

D1 0 1 1N4003

Rsh1 1 0 1e6

Rse1 out 1 0.01

Vo1 out 0 SIN  (0 0.85 50 0 0 0)

Isc1 1 0 5A

.MODEL 1N4003 D( IS=76.9p RS=42.0m BV=200 IBV=5.00u 
+CJO=39.8p  M=0.333 N=1.45 TT=4.32u ) 

.tran 0.01ms 5ms uic
 
.end
```

I am getting an error.

The result of IV curve does not match the real solar photovoltaic I_V characteristic.

1. Voc:

[image]

2. Isc:

[image]

3. Isc Vs Voc:

[image]

Comment: Search for "how to make a SPICE subcircuit", since you already have the circuit (which makes the title of your question and the question, itself, rather different).

Comment: Please do search for some more documentation on how to use a solar panel, because it looks like you don't really know how to use it. I could be wrong, of course, but that voltage source at the output *and* you not being able to deduce from the graphs what is happening, don't really work in your favour. Otherwise, you're half way there: you have the netlist, you need the `.subckt` -- one step away.